# Is it possible to develop for the Kinect sensor without having an Xbox 360?

Tags: augmented-reality, kinect, xbox

Is it possible to develop for the Kinect sensor without having an Xbox 360?

We would like to use the Kinect to develop an augmented reality application, but we're not sure if we need to get an Xbox for this.  Do we have to, or can we develop using other platforms?

Comment: The Kinect sensor works with Windows 7 and there are development environments for it, from Microsoft and from the community.  Try Googling:  http://www.google.com/search?q=kinect+sdk

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are other APIs for interacting with the Kinect.

Microsoft has released it's beta API:
http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/kinectsdk/
The caveat with Microsofts' API is that it cannot be licensed for commercial use.  It's also a beta, so functionality is not locked, and there may be bugs.

OpenKinect is an open-source alternative, but it requires a little more work to get up and running:
http://openkinect.org/wiki/Main_Page

Comment: @Nataly - please click the checkmark next to answers so that meddlingwithfire gets credit for it

Answer (score 1):

Yes ! it is very much possible to develop applications and devices on Kinect without the XBOX. Particular instances are in robotics (http://turtlebot.com/) and 3D printing (http://www.makerbot.com/blog/2011/05/26/3d-printing-with-kinect/). You should be able to get your project done using OpenNI drivers (http://www.openni.org/).